# FireDAC -15 Duplicate Row found on unique index con Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, delphi, timestamp

Estoy trabajando con Delphi XE7 con los componentes de FireDAC y con conexión a una base de datos de *Oracle*, al activar un *TFDTable* y realizar un *First* y luego un *Next* de una tabla que cuenta con una llave primaria que tiene 3 campos, el primero es de tipo NUMBER(10,0), el segundo es de tipo TIMESTAMP(4) y el tercero es de tipo CHAR(10), recibo el error:

**Error: [Nombre_tabla] (1): -15. Duplicate row found on unique index. Constraint[Nombre_índice_PK].**

Al obtener el primer registro observo que el valor de mi columna TimesTamp(4) solo me llega como: '2020-01-28 14:15:34.000' y en la BD tengo los registros con milésimas de segundo como los siguientes, la diferencia solo radica en las milésimas:

```
2020-01-28 14:15:34.1702
2020-01-28 14:15:34.1654
2020-01-28 14:15:34.1842
2020-01-28 14:15:34.2025
```

Si obtengo el valor a través de SQL Server que tiene la misma tabla y registros obtengo el valor de '2020-01-28 14:15:34.170', el tipo de dato en SQL Server es Datetime2(4), lo que quiere decir que me esta truncando las milésimas al utilizar ORACLE, necesito evitar que se trunquen las milésimas espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿estás utilizando TClientDatasets?

Comment: Si, si lo utilizo

Answer (score 1):

Como comentas que está utilizando TClientDataset, revisa que la propiedad `UpdateMode`
del `TDatasetProvider` asociado esté a valor `upWhereKeyOnly`.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Datasnap.Provider.TBaseProvider.UpdateMode

Por defecto, tiene valor `upWhereAll` y esto provoca errores a la hora de "encontrar" los registros.
Valida por favor si esto ha solventado tu problema. Sin más datos es difícil estar seguro 100% si es esto.

Comment: He revisado esa propiedad y si la tengo con el valor de upWhereKeyOnly, el error me sigue apareciendo incluso también con tipos de dato FLOAT, en la base de datos tengo un valor de 12.2564894521 y al obtener este valor en mi proyecto solo recibo 12.256489452, alguna propiedad que sea de su conocimiento para evitar que FireDAC corte los decimales?, solo me muestra hasta 10 decimales

Comment: Este problema es distinto. Para el tema de redondeo deberías revisar el tipo de campo que tienes definido y ver si lo puedes cambiar por otro con más precisión.

Comment: Ya lo he revisado ese si se debe a el tipo de dato que se estaba utilizando en Oracle, gracias:)

Comment: Respecto al tipo de dato de TIMESTAMP(4) sabrás de alguna otra solución? en SQL Server tengo la misma tabla y ahí no se me devuelve el error de esta pregunta